# New Grails3 Website Using Spring Security 4.0.4 Issues

Tags: java, macos, grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

My goal is to have an understanding of grails with spring security, as I am getting familiar with grails. I know the general structure and how GORM works, as well as having decent experience with SQL (particular postgresql).

My current tools / sdk wanted:
java 8
grails 3.1.3
groovy 2.4.4
spring security core 4.0.4
Mac OSX 10.11.3
Intellij IDEA Ultimate 15

I want to have a general structure of secure accounts in my grails powered website, with login, remember me, facebook connect, etc, and the first part is getting a basic setup with spring security in grails3.

Have tried looking at the following resources:

[Grails - Spring Security Core v2 (outdated)](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)

[Spring IO Getting Started (outdated)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

[VERY confusing getting started docs for 4.0.4 (No mention of grails3 either)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#m3to4)

[Grails Plugins for Spring Security 3.0.3 (outdated)](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/view)

[Another grails+spring security instructional (outdated)](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/grails-howto-secure-app-using-spring-security-core)

[Yet another Spring Security Quickstart (outdated)](http://sysgears.com/articles/spring-security-grails-plugin-quick-start-and-some-tips/)

Is there any nice concrete examples of v4 with grails 3?
I am unsure how to follow the 4.0.4 document, as it is very confusing and I'm not even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, but this is the up-to-date documentation for the Grails Spring Security Core plugin for Grails 3: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/

The version numbers are confusing, but the plugin version is 3.0.3 and that is using spring security 4.0.x as its core libraries.

Comment: Ahhh, dang it. I wouldn't have guessed that the version numbers would be different... :/ Why can't they be the same...